# jquery library conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use two jQuery Library in a single page (Tab & Gallery) for both used two different versions of jQuery libraries now it both wont work at a time. i have to remove a library to work another.

Used versions

[1.7.1 jQuery.mini.js for Gallery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)

[1.6.2 jQuery.mini.js - for tab](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js)

**and**

this one

--http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js

Here how i used this coding

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script // type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please tell a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use the newest source! And place it before the jQuery UI. It is better to get your files from the same source, perferably a CDN, like Google's.

These are the newest versions, you are using out-dated ones.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still gallery wont work

below i have given the links to gallery java scripts. please check

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.tmpl.min.js

--http://tympanus.net/codrops/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.elastislide.js

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/gallery.js

--http://tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/csscustom.js

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference the jQuery library twice - it will attempt to override the functionality and break your script. You just need to reference it once:

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i use only this part of jquery lib. it gallery wont work.

Here is gallery used jQuery

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.tmpl.min.js

--http://tympanus.net/codrops/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.elastislide.js

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/gallery.js

--http://tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/csscustom.js

Answer (score 0):

Just don't include jQuery twice...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still gallery wont work

below i have given the links to gallery java scripts. please check

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.tmpl.min.js

--http://tympanus.net/codrops/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/jquery.elastislide.js

--http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/js/gallery.js

--http://tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/csscustom.js

Answer (score 0):

you may be polluting the name space. change $ to jQuery, use noconflict() or use self invoking anonymous function